# Merging two DataFrames using an aggregate on a column on one of the DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

In Python-Pandas, lets say I have two DataFrames

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'key1': np.random.randint(4, size=10), 'val1': np.random.rand(10) })

B = pd.DataFrame({'key1': np.random.randint(4, size=10), 'val2': np.random.rand(10) })
```

I want to add a column to B which is the mean of the values of ‘val1’ in A grouped by each key (keys refer to the same index in both A and B). What’s the best way to do this?

*Here is what worked for me*

```
A1 = A.groupby('key1')['val1'].mean().reset_index()
B.merge(A1 , on='key1', how='left', sort=False, right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
A1 = A.groupby('key1').mean().reset_index()
pd.merge(B, A1, on='key1')
```

Comment: Does the 2nd line merge A1 into B, or do I need to say `B = pd.merge(B, A1, on='key1')`

Comment: @user3487187 The merger is not performed "in-place", no. You'll have to assign it.

Comment: Thanks. A couple of follow ups: a) what if 'val2' is actually called 'val1' in B? Is there a way to give the mean of val1 a different name? b) What if there are some keys in B that are not in A... Is there a way to assign mean(val1) = 0 for those missing keys so as to not lose entries in B

Comment: @user3487187 See the docs on [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging). `pd.merge()` takes a `suffix` argument tuple that will be appended to the column names if they are the same, like `val1_x` and `val1_y`. You may, of course, choose to rename the columns from `A` before merging. Also, setting `how='left'` in merge will cause an SQL-style left-join; i.e., the values in `B` will persist whether they exist in `A` or not. My advice is to read the docs and play around with the above two commands until you find what you want.